# Having trouble exporting data to specific rows in excel sheet

Tags: r, excel

So I'm building this function that will pull data from a website and accumulate it in an excel spreadsheet. But am having trouble loading the package and want to figure out what I might be missing.

I've learned that a good package to help with this is the "xlsx" package in R. So naturally I install and load it into my working environment but get this error when R reaches that line of code:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so Reason: image not found

Also here is the code that I've written to eventually load datasets into the excel spreadsheet.

```
write.xlsx(aa, "Database.xlsx", sheetName= "Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE, showNA= TRUE)
write.xlsx(ab, "Database.xlsx", sheetName= "Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE, showNA= TRUE)
write.xlsx(ha, "Database.xlsx", sheetName= "Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE, showNA= TRUE)
write.xlsx(hb, "Database.xlsx", sheetName= "Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE, showNA= TRUE)
```

If anyone can provide some insight on what the potential problem might be it would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Many packages that create xlsx files from R depend on the rJava package (and hence a java installation on your machine), which is notorious for installation issues. Googling around for that issue will lead to LOTS of information. There is also the `openxlsx` package which is quite powerful and does not rely on java at all. Another option is `writexl`, but while it does not use java, it has many fewer features.

Comment: I used xlsx for a long time and then switched to openxlsx which was such a relief. I can only recommend it!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Openxlsx has been working wonders for me